# Tree with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, tree, hierarchy

I have a simple structure like this

```
class Host{
   Node RootNode;
}
class Node{
   Node Parent;
   Children ICollection<Node>Children;
}
```

And I have the model builder as

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.Parent)
    .WithMany(y => y.Children)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("Parent_Id")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

However, when I query I do not get the whole tree but just the first child. How can I get the whole tree data loaded. Here is the query.

```
return db.Host
         .Include(l => l.RootNode)
```

Comment: switch on `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true` and make sure that all properties have `virtual` keyword annotation

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov I needed the data to be eagerly loaded hence the .include.  I added the virtual keyword. Somehow loading a tree with EF seems a bit of challenge.

Comment: I got it working, sorry, my data reference was wrong. However I found that it works different for single reference as to list. I mean one tree which is single child and other one children.   

    db.Host.Include(l => l.RootLevel).Include(g => g.RootNode)
                .Include(g => g.RootLevel.Child.Child.Child.Child.Child)
                .Include(g => g.RootNode.Children)